# Select previous date for each row in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table that tracks machine maintenance which happen at arbitrary points in time. Here's a simplified table structure:

```
Maintenance Table
----------------------------------------
ID            - integer
DateCompleted - date
MachineName   - varchar
```

and here's some sample table data:

```
ID   DateCompleted MachineName
----------------------------------------
1     1/6/2011     'Machine 1'
2     1/13/2011    'Machine 2'
3     1/14/2011    'Machine 1'
4     2/2/2011     'Machine 3'
5     2/26/2011    'Machine 1'
6     3/9/2011     'Machine 2'
7     4/20/2011    'Machine 3'
```

What I'm trying to do is create a query that will return the date from the previous maintenance task for each task. So the result set would be like this:

```
ID   MachineName  CurDate     PrevDate
----------------------------------------
1    'Machine 1'    1/6/2011    NULL
2    'Machine 2'    1/13/2011   NULL
3    'Machine 1'    1/14/2011   1/6/2011
4    'Machine 3'    2/2/2011    NULL
5    'Machine 1'    2/26/2011   1/14/2011
6    'Machine 2'    3/9/2011    1/13/2011
7    'Machine 3'    4/20/2011   2/2/2011
```

What would be the best way to write such a query? My only idea so far would be something like this:

```
SELECT ID, MachineName, DateCompleted AS CurDate,
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 DateCompleted FROM Maintenance m2
    WHERE m1.MachineName = m2.MachineName
      AND m1.DateCompleted > m2.DateCompleted
    ORDER BY DateCompleted DESC
  ) AS PrevDate

FROM Maintenance m1

ORDER BY ID
```

Any thoughts, suggestions, or corrections would be very welcome.

Comment: Microsoft, but I welcome solutions for any.

Comment: "Microsoft" isn't an RDBMS. "SQL Server" is a dbms.  I tagged it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said "*but I welcome solutions for any*".

This is a solution with ANSI SQL:

```
SELECT ID, 
       DateCompleted, 
       MachineName, 
       lag(DateCompleted) over (partition by MachineName order by DateCompleted) as PrevDate 
FROM Maintenance 
ORDER BY id;
```

Works in PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2 and Teradata.

SQL Server does not yet support the `lag()` function, but the upcoming "Denali" version (2012) will have it.

Comment: That is a neat feature. Too bad it's not supported by everybody.

Comment: @Sparafusile: windowing functions are an important feature (like recursive queries) and nowadays I consider a DBMS not supporting them not to be "state of the art" any longer (Firebird 3.0 will also have them)

Comment: Correct, I misread your statement. I thought you said "Windows" as in Microsoft. After more reading I realized my mistake. This is the type of solution I was looking for, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT
    m.ID, m.MachineName, m.DateCompleted AS CurDate, MAX(m_past.DateCompleted) AS PrevDate

FROM Maintenance m

    LEFT JOIN Maintenance m_past
    ON m.MachineName = m_past.MachineName

WHERE m_past.DateCompleted < m.DateCompleted

GROUP BY m.ID
```

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` will prevent you from selecting `m.MachineName, m.DateCompleted AS CurDate`. I would suggest removing `m.ID` from the select, and grouping by `m.MachineName, m.DateCompleted`.

Comment: Is this better, performance-wise, than my original solution? If so, why?

Comment: @jzilla: You may be right, but I don't see it. Also, if it's true, couldn't I just use `GROUP BY m.ID, m.MachineName, m.DateCompleted`?
@Sparafusile: I think your method will perform inner queries (one per row) while mine won't. Though the `JOIN` might make it retrieve more data in total, you'll need to test. Don't forget to put an index on `MachineName`!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Id, A.MachineName, A.DateCompleted [CurDate], B.DateCompleted PrevDate
FROM Maintenance  A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM Maintenance 
             WHERE MachineName = A.MachineName AND DateCompleted < A.DateCompleted
             ORDER BY DateCompleted DESC) B
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether TOP n works depends on your dbms. MAX() will work across platforms. Index DateCompleted and MachineName; they're both used in the WHERE clause.

```
select m1.id, m1.machinename, m1.datecompleted as curdate,
  ( select max(datecompleted)
    from maintenance
    where machinename = m1.machinename
      and datecompleted < m1.datecompleted ) as prevdate
from maintenance m1
order by machinename, curdate
```

If your dbms supports windowing functions, you can use

```
select m1.id, m1.machinename, m1.datecompleted as curdate, 
       max(datecompleted) over (partition by machinename 
                                order by m1.datecompleted 
                                rows between unbounded preceding 
                                         and 1 preceding) as prevdate
from maintenance m1
```

I wouldn't try to guess which will be faster. I'd load a table with as much sample data as you expect to have, and test both of them. Then I'd reload it with 10 times as much data and test again.

In the process of testing, you want to learn how to [generate and read an execution plan](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/sql-server/getting-an-execution-plan).

Comment: Thank you. This is essentially the same as my solution though. I was hoping for something profound that I hadn't though of yet.

Comment: Good that you know about windowing functions. Generating data is always more costly than storing it.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

```
declare @tmp table (Id int, DateCompleted datetime, MachineName varchar(100))
insert into @tmp
select 1,'1/6/2011','Machine 1'
union select 2,'1/13/2011',    'Machine 2'
union select 3,'1/14/2011',    'Machine 1'
union select 4,'2/2/2011',     'Machine 3'
union select 5,'2/26/2011',    'Machine 1'
union select 6,'3/9/2011',     'Machine 2'
union select 7,'4/20/2011',    'Machine 3'



select t.Id, t.DateCompleted, t.MachineName, max(t2.DateCompleted) PrevDate
from @tmp t
left join @tmp t2
    on t.MachineName = t2.MachineName
    and t.DateCompleted > t2.DateCompleted
group by t.Id, t.DateCompleted, t.MachineName
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with SQL Server 2012 you can use windowed aggregates to write the query you need. Just use the following code:

```
select
    ID, 
    MachineName, 
    DateCompleted AS CurDate,
    min(DateCompleted) 
        over (partition by MachineName order by DateCompleted 
            rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as PrevDate
from Maintenance
order by Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems reasonable to me, and it is easy to understand.  Ignoring the possible cost of the final sort, I believe the complexity is essentially O(n log n) assuming that the appropriate indexes exist.  For each entry in the table, a the query engine must locate the previous date entry, which should be O(log n) with the correct indexes.

One way to *maybe* increase the performance at the cost of code complexity would be to write a stored procedure to produce the result.  I think the unordered result could be produced in O(n).  The procedure could iterate through two cursors on the table ordered by `MachineName` and then by `DateCompleted`.  It could construct the result set in O(n) as it stepped through both cursors.  However, the result would then need to be sorted on ID, which would be O(n log n).  So I think the theoretical complexity would be the same as the query, but the procedure might have less overhead and run a bit faster.  But I definitely would not recommend that solution because it would be ugly and much harder to maintain.

Comment: It's actually quite easy and can done by a single table scan for any DBMS supporting windowing functions. See my answer.